# Initial value problem and limits

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I need some help finishing this one. Hints would also be much appreciated!

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d y}{d x}+\frac{y}{\tanh (x)} &=14 \frac{\cosh (x)}{\sinh (1)} \\
y(1) &=b
\end{aligned}
$$

Find the value of $b$ that that ensures that lim $x \rightarrow 0+y(x)$ exists.

---

Solving the diff.equation:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
e^{\int \frac{1}{\tanh (x)}}=e^{\ln( \sinh (x))}=\sinh (x) \\
\frac{d y}{d x} \sinh (x)+\frac{y \sinh( x)}{\tanh (x)}=\frac{14}{\sinh (1)} \cosh (x) \sinh( x) \\
U=\sinh (x) \\
 \int (y \sinh (x))^{\prime}=\frac{14}{\sinh (1)}\int\frac{U\cosh(x)}{\cosh (x)}\, \mathrm dU \\
\qquad y \sinh (x)=\frac{14}{\sinh( 1)}\left(\frac{U^{2}}{2}+c\right) \\
y=\frac{14 \sinh( x)}{\sinh (1)}+\frac{14 c}{\sinh( x) \sinh (1)}
\end{array}
$$

So..here it kinda stops. Given the condition $y(1)=b$  I've been very tempted into thinking that I can show $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} y(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{ x\to 1} y(x)$. (From the definition of limit, where $0$ is 'left' of $0^+$ and $1$ is 'right' of 0^+1, but I guess this is wrong)

Comment: @Migr: Are you sure that solution is correct?

Comment: No i'm not, however I do not immediately see what i've done wrong myself so it would be nice if someone could lead me in the right direction! (if my integration is wrong..)

Comment: @Migr Check your solution. It should be $y(x)=C\cdot \operatorname{csch}(x)+14.$